# Evaluate an && condition only for rows with matching times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

The following is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
               SC.Feature, 
               CASE WHEN SA.Target > ANY(SELECT SA.Availability) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsAvailable,
               SA.Date AS DateTime

FROM           dbo.ServiceAvailability AS SA LEFT OUTER JOIN
               dbo.ServiceCatalog AS SC ON SA.ServiceID = SC.ServiceID
```

My output ends up being of this form:

```
Feature    IsAvailable    DateTime
-------------------------------------------------
  F1            0         2014-11-01 07:00:00.000 
  F1            1         2014-11-01 07:00:00.000
```

How do I change my query to `AND` the output such that I would instead get those two rows to combine into the below?

```
Feature    IsAvailable    DateTime
-------------------------------------------------
  F1            0         2014-11-01 07:00:00.000
```

EDIT: If both the `IsAvailable` values were 1, of course they would both `AND` and combine to give a single row with `IsAvailable = 1`

Comment: How do the two rows combine into one and have IsAvailable=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT
               SC.Feature, 
               CASE WHEN sum(
                       CASE WHEN SA.Target > ANY(SELECT SA.Availability) 
                          THEN 1 
                          ELSE 0 
                       END) >= 1 
                    THEN 0 
                    ELSE 1 
               END AS IsAvailable,
               SA.Date AS DateTime

FROM           dbo.ServiceAvailability AS SA 
LEFT JOIN      dbo.ServiceCatalog AS SC ON SA.ServiceID = SC.ServiceID
GROUP BY       SC.Feature, 
               SA.Date
```

I reversed the inner CASE statement so `0` is now `1` and vice versa. Then we can sum that grouped by your group columns, and if the sum is greater-or-equal to 1 then there was at least one `1` (which is actually a `0`!), and therefore the result of the *and* operation will be `0`; otherwise they were all `0` (actually `1`) and the result should be `1`.

**Edit:** In response to "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery" - I didn't realise that was a limitation. I've rearranged the query to perform the subqueries first and then group on that dataset. Hopefully this works. I think it's a little clearer what's happening now as well.

```
SELECT
    Feature,
    CASE WHEN sum(IsNotAvailable) >= 1 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
    END AS IsAvailable,
    [DateTime]
FROM (
    SELECT      
                   SC.Feature,                
                   CASE WHEN SA.Target > ANY(SELECT SA.Availability) 
                      THEN 1 
                      ELSE 0 
                   END AS IsNotAvailable,
                   SA.Date AS DateTime    
    FROM           dbo.ServiceAvailability AS SA 
    LEFT JOIN      dbo.ServiceCatalog AS SC ON SA.ServiceID = SC.ServiceID
) x
GROUP BY       x.Feature, 
               x.[DateTime]
```

Comment: This makes sense to me. However it spits out the error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Answer (score 0):

for **And** between two operands if only one operand's value be **0** the result will be **0**
so I think this will solve your problem:

```
select distinct * 
 from (SELECT DISTINCT 
           SC.Feature, 
           CASE WHEN SA.Target > ANY(SELECT SA.Availability) THEN 0 ELSE 1 EN
 IsAvailable,
           SA.Date AS DateTime

 FROM           dbo.ServiceAvailability AS SA LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.ServiceCatalog AS SC ON SA.ServiceID = SC.ServiceID) 
 where IsAvailable=0
```

Comment: This doesn't return any of the cases where IsAvailable is 1, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this where it is selecting the distinct rows from your original query

```
select distinct * 
from (SELECT 
       SC.Feature, 
       CASE WHEN SA.Target > ANY(SELECT SA.Availability) THEN 0 ELSE 1 EN
IsAvailable,
       SA.Date AS DateTime

 FROM           dbo.ServiceAvailability AS SA LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.ServiceCatalog AS SC ON SA.ServiceID = SC.ServiceID)
```

Comment: This does not change my output.